# FutureWarning from signaltools.py

Tags: scipy, future-warning

```
from scipy.signal import resample
A = np.array([1,2,3])
resample(A, 6)
```

... works, but throws a warning:

> /Users/pi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/signaltools.py:2223: **FutureWarning**: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
>     Y[sl] = X[sl]
>
> /Users/pi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/signaltools.py:2225: **FutureWarning**: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
>     Y[sl] = X[sl]

My scipy version is 1.1.0 (up to date).

Is this something I should be reporting to the scipy dev team?

PS reference: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html

Answer (score 2):

Inspecting the line of failure on my own filesystem (`.../scipy/signal/signaltools.py:2223`), and matching against the current scipy master (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/signaltools.py#L2249) I can see that this issue has been fixed.

I just need to wait for 1.2 to come out!